# How to get Ip address of other devices connected on same network via Wifi programmatically?

Tags: android, ip, wifi, ip-address, android-wifi

I have checked it in my Android mobile. After enabling Wifi it has shown me which network has been connected then it is also provided details like obtaining specific network Ip address, Signal strength and so on.

Could I able to do this in Android version 2.3 programmatically?

Comment: i think its hard you should probably have a root permission and ll have to ping for each adresess and wait for replay but we can assume that ur ip -1 ip are all aloted to devices ;) anyways +1

Comment: How can i have a root permission and have to ping each addresses? Can you tell me how it is possible ?

Comment: it depends on each mobile if you are having an htc they provide it i don't know about the rest and i think this forum don't discuss such things --what is that you want to do exactly??

Answer (score 0):

Router assigns IP to the connected devices in a range. For example say from :

> 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254

This you can figure out based on your device subnet and gateway as shown below-

> Address:   192.168.0.1     =>      11000000.10101000.00000000 .00000001
>
> Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   => 11111111.11111111.11111111 .00000000
>
> Wildcard:  0.0.0.255        =>     00000000.00000000.00000000 .11111111
>
> =>
>
> Network:   192.168.0.0/24   =>     11000000.10101000.00000000 .00000000 (Class C)
>
> Broadcast: 192.168.0.255   =>   11000000.10101000.00000000 .11111111
>
> HostMin:   192.168.0.1      =>     11000000.10101000.00000000 .00000001
>
> HostMax:   192.168.0.254    =>     11000000.10101000.00000000 .11111110
>
> Hosts/Net: 254                   (Private Internet)

Now Try to send PING command from your device in the range 192.168.0.1 to  192.168.0.254 and if you get a reply, In this way you can figure it out about the other devices present in your network.